# Until statement waiting for process to finish being ignored

Tags: bash, shell-script, osx

I am trying to automate installation of git without using sudo privileges, a nice (but slow) workaround is to install Xcode which comes bundled with git as `xcode-select --install` can be invoked by a standard user

```
#!/bin/bash
# check if user has git installed
which git &> /dev/null
OUT=$?
sleep 3


# if output of git check is not 0(not foud) then run installer
if [ ! $OUT -eq 0 ]; then
    xcode_dialog () {
        XCODE_MESSAGE="$(osascript -e 'tell app "System Events" to display dialog "Please click install when Command Line Developer Tools appears"')"
        if [ "$XCODE_MESSAGE" = "button returned:OK" ]; then
            xcode-select --install
        else
            echo "You have cancelled the installation, please rerun the installer."
        fi
    }
    xcode_dialog
fi

# get xcode installer process ID by name and wait for it to finish
until  [ ! "$(pgrep -i 'Install Command Line Developer Tools')" ]; do
    sleep 1
done

echo 'Xcode has finished installing'

which git &> /dev/null
OUT=$?
if [ $OUT = 0 ]; then
    echo 'Xcode was installed incorrectly'
    exit 1
fi
```

My `until` statement however gets completely ignored and the second check for git gets triggered almost as soon as `XCODE_MESSAGE` returns OK. Anyone know how the logic to wait for the installer to finish could be better implemented?

Comment: Are you sure your command `pgrep -i 'Install Command Line Developer Tools'` finds the command you are looking for in the process list? if so, have you tried putting some trace inside your loop, somehing like `date  +%HH:MM:SS`?

Comment: It reliably gets a pid, the difficulty with testing this is that I have to do it on a fresh computer or a sanbox environment since once xcode is installed it becomes hard to test.

Comment: the was a typo in my first comment - I proposed to add `date +%H:%M:%S`. So can you try additing this or `echo "some test'` inside your until command between do and done? What I'm trying to understand is whether it ever goes inside. One more thought - the installation may start after some time - do you want trying to add sleep 3 before the until?

Comment: I had a `printf` that said 'waiting on installer' that I took out for sake of clarity as well as a `sleep 3` before the `until` call

Comment: than just simplify your code - remove last 10 rows of your code and add  few lines with something like  `until [ "$(which git)" ]; do echo "I'm still waiting, I'm still hoping"; sleep 3; done`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would slightly change the approach you follow in your script: check that "git" exists rather than check that installation process is not running:

```
#!/bin/bash

# check if user has git installed and propose to install if not installed
if [ "$(which git)" ]; then
        echo "You already have git. Exiting.."
        exit
else
        XCODE_MESSAGE="$(osascript -e 'tell app "System Events" to display dialog "Please click install when Command Line Developer Tools appears"')"
        if [ "$XCODE_MESSAGE" = "button returned:OK" ]; then
            xcode-select --install
        else
            echo "You have cancelled the installation, please rerun the installer."
            # you have forgotten to exit here
            exit
        fi
fi

until [ "$(which git)" ]; do
        echo -n "."
        sleep 1
done
echo ""

echo 'Xcode has finished installing'
```

Comment: This is simpler and smarter check to implement, thanks!